# Airflow - Copy blob from/to Google Cloud Storage within 2 different projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to copy a blob from the GCS bucket A in the project X to the bucket B in the project Y using Airflow.

It seems that the available operator (GCSToGCSOperator) works well only between two buckets within the same project.

How can I have achieve the copy in my case?

I'd like to avoid using a BashOperator...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Using `CloudDataTransferServiceCreateJobOperator` which creates a transfer job using [Google API](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJob). You can find information about it in [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/cloud_storage_transfer_service.html#google-cloud-transfer-service-operators). Note that this require the service account to have access to both. If this is not the case then it's not supported yet See [Use Google Storage Transfer API to transfer data from external GCS into my GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949241/use-google-storage-transfer-api-to-transfer-data-from-external-gcs-into-my-gcs)

**Option 2:**
Use `GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator` with project 1 and then `LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator` using project 2.

A skeleton of this solution:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.local_to_gcs import LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_local import GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator

with DAG(
    "example", schedule_interval="@daily", start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1), catchup=False
) as dag:
    download = GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator(
        task_id="download_task",
        bucket='some_bucket',
        filename='/tmp/fake1.csv',
        object_name="test/test1.csv",
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_origin'
    )
    
    upload = LocalFilesystemToGCSOperator(
        task_id='upload_task',
        bucket='some_bucket',
        src='/tmp/fake1.csv',
        dst='test/test1.csv',
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_dest'
    )

    download >> upload
```

Though this is not ideal solution. It really depends on the volumes and frequency of your job. With this solution you are transferring files via the local disk - in small volumes it can be fine. This solution will work in cases of two distinct accounts as each operator is associated to a different Google connection.

Comment: Hi Elad, thanks for your great support, I'll try to follow your suggestions! But, just to understand, it is confirmed that the GCSToGCSOperator operator cannot work on different projects?

Comment: @walzer91 yes. You can check the source code and see that it doesn't have that support.