# GCStoGCSOperator Move option across projects Composer/Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

So I'm utilizing the `GCStoGCSOperator` to grab a report from the reporting API then doing a few updates to the report in a Project, but then when I try to move that file to Project 2 its throwing an error stating that bucket doesn't exist.

I currently have a SA account that is attached to both GCS buckets in both Projects. But, I'm unable to do the following Operator:

```
move_single_file = GCSToGCSOperator(
    task_id="move_single_file",
    source_bucket=BUCKET_1_SRC,
    source_object=OBJECT_1,
    destination_bucket=BUCKET_1_DST,
    destination_object="backup_" + OBJECT_1,
    move_object=True,
)
```

Where `BUCKET_1_SRC` is `Project 1` and `BUCKET_1_DST` is `Project 2`. How would I go about doing this to make it so it moves a file from `Project 1` and moves it over to `Project 2`? I'm currently getting a `404 POST Error` stating that the `Bucket does not exist`. Is there a `destination_project` variable that I may be missing in this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow - Copy blob from/to Google Cloud Storage within 2 different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023049/airflow-copy-blob-from-to-google-cloud-storage-within-2-different-projects)

Comment: Available parameters can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_gcs/index.html) `destination_project` can be specified as an argument within the `destination_bucket='destination_project'`