# GCP Composer: Run Python Script in another GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm new to Airflow, and I'm trying to run a python script that reads data from Bigquery, does some preprocessing, and exports a table back to Bigquery. This is the dag I have

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

YESTERDAY = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
   'owner': 'me',
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'start_date': YESTERDAY,
   'email': [''],
   'email_on_failure': False,
   'email_on_retry': False,
   'retries': 0,
   'max_tries': 0,
}

with DAG(
   dag_id = 'my_code',
   default_args = default_args,
   schedule_interval = '@daily',
   catchup  = False
) as dag:

   import data = BashOperator(
          task_id = 'daily_task',
          bash_command = 'python gs://project_id/folder1/python_script.py'
         )
```

This gives an error of 'No such file or directory found'. I did not set up the Environment in Composer, so I'm not sure if it requires specific credentials. I tried storing the script in the dags folder, but then it wasn't able to access the bigquery tables.

I have two questions:

1. How do I properly define the location of the python script within another GCS bucket? Should the gs location work if proper credentials are applied? Or do I necessarily have to store the scripts in a folder within the dags folder?
2. How do I provide the proper credentials (like login ID and password) within the DAG, in case that is all that's needed to solve the issues?

I handwrote the code since the original is in a work laptop and I cannot copy. Let me know if there are any errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, I propose you a solution which in my opinion, is easier to manage.
Whenever possible it is better to use Python scripts within Composer's Bucket.

- Copy your `Python` script in the `Composer` bucket and `DAG` folder with a separated process outside of Composer (gcloud) or directly in the DAG. If you want to do that in the `DAG`, you can check from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023049/airflow-copy-blob-from-to-google-cloud-storage-within-2-different-projects)
- Use a `Python` operator that invokes your `Python` script inside the `DAG`
- The `Service Account` used by `Composer` needs having the good privileges to read and write data to `BigQuery`. If you copy the `Python` scripts directly in the `DAG`, the SA needs to have the privileges to download file from `GCS` in the project 2.

```py
from your_script import your_method_with_bq_logic
   
with airflow.DAG(
        'your_dag',
        default_args=your_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    
    
    bq_processing = PythonOperator(
        task_id='bq_processing',
        python_callable=your_method_with_bq_logic
    )

    bq_processing
```

You can import the `Python` script main method in the code because it exists in the `DAG` folder.

Comment: @tejas have you solved your issue ?

Comment: Yes, I got the necessary permissions for Composer, but it seems the python script takes too much resources to be run on Composer.